# AWS Cloudwatch Client Put_Targets - Failing on Paramater Validation Unknown "LaunchType"

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs, botocore

I am trying to Schedule a Task for ECS Fargate using Cloudwatch Client Put_targets method.

I am getting the following error.

```
ParamValidationError('Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in Targets[0].EcsParameters: "LaunchType", must be one of: TaskDefinitionArn, TaskCount\nUnknown parameter in Targets[0].EcsParameters: "NetworkConfiguration", must be one of: TaskDefinitionArn, TaskCount
```

I am thinking maybe the support for Fargate is not yet integrated ?

Boto3 Version: 1.9.14

Botocore Version: 1.12.14

Python: 3.6.1